# Rails 3: has_many and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-many

I have the following models

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many      :dealers 
end

class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :city
end
```

I need to find all the cities which have dealers. How do I go about writing the `where()` to get the desired results?

Comment: What are the attributes of `dealers` table?

Comment: dealer will have `city_id`

Comment: Try with this `City.joins(:dealers).where("dealers.city_id =?",city.id)`

Comment: get `undefined local variable or method 'city'`

Comment: Try this `City.joins(:dealers).where("dealers.city_id =?",id)`

Comment: getting `undefined local variable or method 'id'`. May have to go with something like `City.joins(:dealers).select('DISTINCT(dealers.city_id)')` but am not sure yet.

Comment: That would do the trick i guess so.Try with your query.

Comment: the DISTINCT is not giving me the complete record of the City. Where as i need it to work with. Have found an alternative, adding as my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some of the options this is what I came up with.

```
City.joins(:dealers).group("dealers.city_id")
```

this returns the complete records of the cities.

Edit after finding a better way.

Well there is a better way to achieve this as well and that is by using the `uniq` in the select. So the new query will be

```
City.joins(:dealers).uniq
```

which translates to

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cities`.* FROM `cities` INNER JOIN `dealers` ON `dealers`.`city_id` = `cities`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

To find only the cities that have dealers:

```
City.joins(:dealers)
```

If a city has no dealers then it will not be returned in the results.

Comment: This does not give me the distinct cities rather all the cities * all the dealers. and I need the distinct cities.